# Setting the parameterless constructor as the injection constructor in container creation

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a class with two ctors. One parameterless and one with parameters.
Unity will by default take the gready approach and go for the last ctor.

How can I define what ctor to use (I want to parameterless) without adding dependency on Unity within my classes? I think it is possible to do it in my container creation, but I don't know how.

Currently my registration entry looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigurationService, SqlConfigurationService>()
```

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to avoid programming in XML (config file) as much as possible.

**EXTRA**
How would registering a constructor with one parameter (which in it's turn should be injected)?
Say ILoggerService is already registered and I would want to use the constructor

```
public SqlConfigurationService(ILoggerService logger){}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't have Unity nearby right now, but as far as I recall, you can do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigurationService, SqlConfigurationService>(
    new InjectionConstructor())
```

Comment: Thanks :) Do you per chance also know how to solve my extra question (bottom of OP)?

Comment: Total guess after looking a bit at the API docs: `container.RegisterType<IConfigurationService, SqlConfigurationService>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ILoggerService>()));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also pass in an InjectionConstructor (including `ResolvedParameter<T>`s for the parameters) in your registration. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the InjectionConstructor attribute to the constructor you want to use. This does have the disadvantange of moving some container configuration away from a central location however.

Comment: I don't want to add any dependency in my actual classes (ref OP)